# (Oracle) SQL String Manipulation Update - Replace URL Substring

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

**(Oracle)**

I need to do a SQL update on a table column that stores URL strings. All strings in that column that look like

```
http://abc.site.com/...
```

should be replaced with

```
http://def.site.com/...
```

Is there a quick way to do this string replacement in SQL for the rows that satisfy the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm):

```
update tbl
set col = replace(col, 'http://abc.site.com/', 'http://def.site.com/')
where col like '%http://abc.site.com/%'
```

Comment: I need to actually update the values that are stored.

Comment: One more issue. The original string is not *exactly* http://abc.site.com/, there is other stuff following it. Will the replace catch it?

Comment: @geneb.: `like` will catch it, `replace` will just change one substring to another.